# Location mining from text

Tags: data-mining, text-mining

I'm working on a text mining problem: extract the place from the text. The place could be either only states, or more specific such as name of a neighborhood in Chicago, or even a specific address. But it's only in US.

I've been trying Yahoo Place maker api, but I can't create the api key ( the website is not responding). Is there anyway to do it, such as rapid miner, or write a comprehensive regex?

Comment: Regex would not work for this, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397485/regex-street-address-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER). Online demo here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process

It's a java library. License is GPL v2, though the license to distribute in a standalone app is pricey.

Comment: Is there anyway to use rapidminer for this purpose?

Comment: There is the Information Extraction plugin for RapidMiner but I've tried it a few times and don't really understand it.