# javascript validation for home address. Ex: #55 Bernahrd Gym

Tags: javascript

I need a validation for address that can have Numbers, alphabets, space in two words should be able .. but no space in the beginning of the address. 
The only symbol should be **#**
**EX: #55 Bernahrd Gym**

`Address:<input type="text" required="required" name="baguio_add"><br>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397485/regex-street-address-match

Comment: Your title is "javascript validation" so why did you tag it with php?

Comment: use trim function and indexof function to detect 1st letter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for this: [`/[a-z0-9\s\#]+/i`](https://regex101.com/r/jD0pH2/1)

Instead of testing for spaces at the start, just use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) (or [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)).

---

Edit: You changed your tag to Javascript, you can still use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for this using the regex above.

Comment: can you help me in specific way ex: <script>  /[a-z0-9\s\#]+/i </script> beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex if you want only one #, and any number of alpha numeric plus spaces.

```
/#?[a-zA-Z\s\d]+/
```

If it always starts with # then:

```
/^(#?)[a-zA-Z\s\d]+$/
```

Here is how you use it:

HTML:

```
<input name="address" id="address" type="text" />
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('address').onblur = function (e) {
    console.log(this.value);
    var isValid = /^(#?)[a-zA-Z\s\d]+$/.exec(this.value);
    if (isValid){
      // do any action on valid
      this.className = 'valid';
    } else {
        this.className = 'invalid';
    }
}
```

Here is a working example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uua6pp1q/

Comment: can you show example :) how will I add the " /#?[a-zA-Z\s\d]+/"  inside the   <script type="text/javascript"></script> ?Sorry